# What requirement guarantees a zero intersection between subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently learning about direct sums of subspaces of a vector spaces, in particular my book brings up a problem relating to a direct sum between subspaces $\mathbb{U}=\mathrm{Span}\{x^2+1,x^4\}$ and $\mathbb{W}=\mathrm{Span}\{x^3-x,x^3+x^2+1\}$ in vector space $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, where it automatically states that $\mathbb{U}\cap\mathbb{W}=\{\vec{0}\}$.

However, from a surface level, it doesn't seem so apparent to me that $\mathbb{U}\cap\mathbb{W}=\{\vec{0}\}$. Is there a way to easily deduce that this is the case?

In my book example above, $\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{U})=\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{W})<\mathrm{dim}(P_3(\mathbb{R}))$, and $\mathbb{U}\cap\mathbb{W}=\{\vec{0}\}$, but for two planes defined by $\mathbb{M}=\mathrm{Span}\{\vec{m_1},\vec{m_2}\}$ and $\mathbb{N}=\mathrm{Span}\{\vec{n_1},\vec{n_2}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{M}\cap\mathbb{N}\neq\{\vec{0}\}$ as planes that are subspaces can only intersect in a line through the origin, or are equivalent.

In particular given some vector space $\mathbb{V}$ with dimension $n$, and subspaces $\mathbb{A}=\mathrm{Span}\{\vec{a_1},...,\vec{a_k}\}$ and $\mathbb{B}=\mathrm{Span}\{\vec{b_1},...,\vec{b_k}\}$ where $k<n$, is there a relationship that between the basis vectors for both subspaces that is an indicator of their intersection $\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{B}$?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no easy way. However, if you know that $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of an $n$-dimensional space and $\dim U + \dim V > n$, then they must intersect. The converse of that statement is of course false.

If you have given bases $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ of $U$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ of $V$, then $U\cap V=\{0\}$ if and only if the set $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k,v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ is linearly independent.